# After Effects: Importing Illustrator sequence?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have 200 layers in Illustrator CS6. I have another set of the same layers but where basic attributes (position, scale) have changed.

Is there a way to import these two "states" into After Effects CS6 so that I end up with 200 layers animating from state 1 to state 2?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me. Will the final animation have 2 frames and moving objects from frame 1 to 2?

Comment: Yes, what I want to achieve is an animation between "State 1" (for all the 200 objects) and "State 2". I already have the static setups in Illustrator but I want to do the tweening in AE so I need it to recognize that it is the same objects/layers in State 1 as in State 2.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following steps with 4 layers, and it seemed to work.

1. Name the file with the state 1 set, `your-filename-1.ai` and the file with the state 2 set `your-filename-2.ai`. Make sure they are in the same folder
2. Open After Effects, click `File -> Import -> File...` and click `your-filename-1.ai`. Make sure the checkmark is checked as shown below:

[image]

To keep all the individual layers, set `Import As:` to `Composition`.
 3. Now you will have a composition in your project panel named `your-filename` and a folder named `your-filename Layers` that contains all the layers.
 5. Now you can open the composition and check `Frame Blending -> Frame Mix` for every layer that you want to tween.
 6. Don't forget to enable frame blending. The image below shows how to do this:
 [image]

Now you have an animation from state 1 to state 2. To change the animation playback speed you can use time-stretching on a layer-per-layer basis.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Is there any way to have AE recognize the individual layers so that I can apply a per-layer tween instead of a general frame-blending?

Comment: @dani I've updated my answer to recognize individual layers.